# Como atualizar as classes em tempo de execução? EF C# MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Preciso atualizar as classes da minha aplicação pois tem uma função no meu controller que cria uma coluna nova:

```
        public string ListarMapeamento()
    {
        banco.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE RegrasMapeamento add Map_test3 varchar(255);");
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Qual a classe que você quer atualizar? Quais informações nela?

Comment: Quero que meu arquivo .edmx pegue a nova coluna do banco, entende?

Comment: E vai compilar novamente toda vez que mudar?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso!

Comment: Edite a pergunta com informações do código que você utiliza para incluir, excluir e exportar informações da tabela, classe e o que achar necessário que também faça essa transação. Assim poderemos ajudar melhor.